# ¿Que representan los corchetes y :: en c++?

Tags: c++, variables, variables-globales, struct

Tengo este código que copié de internet, pero no sé que significan los `factorial<>` y los `::`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<unsigned int n>
struct factorial{
 enum{
     value = n * factorial<n - 1>::value
 };
};

template<>
struct factorial<0>{
 enum { value = 1 };
};


int main(){
 cout << factorial<7>::value <<endl;
}
```

Comment: En este programa se esta usando una `plantilla` o `template`, te recomiendo que investigues sobre ello. Lo que hay entre `< >` es el tipo de dato que esta usando la plantilla. Por otra parte en C++ se usan mucho las clases, el simbolo `::` indica que pertenece a esa clase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los cuatro puntos `::` son el operador de "*pertenece a...*". Lo que te dice es que lo que hay a la derecha de los cuatro puntos pertenece a lo que hay a la izquierda de los cuatro puntos:

```
Árbol :: Rama
Coche :: Rueda
Mano :: Dedo
Universo :: Galaxia
...
```

Los paréntesis angulares (`<>`) son la manera de pasar parámetros a una plantilla de C++. En tu ejemplo tienes una plantilla (`template`) que recibe un parámetro de tipo `unsigned int`:

```
//      v              v <--- Inicio y fin de la lista de parámetros de plantilla
template<unsigned int n>
//       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- Parámetro plantilla llamado 'n' de tipo 'unsigned int'.
struct factorial
//     ^^^^^^^^^ <--- La plantilla (template) es una estructura (struct) llamada 'factorial'.
```

---

Ahora todo junto:

```
    factorial<7>::value <<endl;
//                ^^^^^ <--- 'value' pertenece a 'factorial'
```

```
    factorial<7>::value <<endl;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Una plantilla llamada 'factorial' que recibe '7' como parámetro.
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la definición de una plantilla para calcular factoriales en tiempo de compilación:

```
template<unsigned int n>
struct factorial{
 enum{
     value = n * factorial<n - 1>::value
 };
};
```

Lo que hace, básicamente, es calcular el valor de `value`. Como puedes observar, el valor de `value` se obtiene de multiplicar el valor de otro `value` por `n`. ¿Qué otro `value` cogemos? Pues el calculado para `factorial<n - 1>`.

Es decir, esta plantilla realiza una serie de calculos recursivos.

¿Cómo conseguimos que se detenga la recursión en algún momento? Especializando la plantilla donde nos intersa... en este caso cuando `n` valga 0:

```
template<>
struct factorial<0>{
 enum { value = 1 };
};
```

Esta especialización reemplaza a la que se generaría por defecto para `n==0`. Esta especialización, en vez de hacer que el valor de `value` dependa de otras especializaciones de la plantilla, fija su valor en 1.

Así:

```
factorial<0>::value = 1;
factorial<1>::value = 1 * factorial<0>::value = 1 * 1 = 1;
factorial<2>::value = 2 * factorial<1>::value = 2 * 1 = 2;
factorial<3>::value = 3 * factorial<2>::value = 3 * 2 = 6;
// ...
```

Dicho esto, y por si aún quedan dudas:

`factorial<0>` son los usos de la plantilla. Dado que la plantilla tiene como tipo un entero, las diferentes especializaciones de la plantilla serán accesibles dando valores al tipo entero:

```
factorial<0>
factorial<1>
// ...
```

Los dos puntos seguidos `::` se utilizan para acceder a propiedades estáticas de los objetos. En este caso se usa para recuperar el valor de `value`, que es un valor constante que se almacena en un enumerado sin nombre.